# Retrieve only durations with negative numbers

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, filter, conditional-statements, google-query-language

Would like to retrieve data from range H, where any duration has negative number. Please bear in mind that I actually have over 10k rows and this is just an example.

[image]

Comment: You haven't shown enough of the sheet to know what the actual row start range is. Also, it's unclear from which columns data should be returned (only the Col-H values? both Col-G and Col-H values? other column data that isn't show?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this:

```
=FILTER(A:B; B:B<0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `=QUERY(G5:H8,"SELECT A,B WHERE B < 0",1)`